# postgresql query does not return anything even if data is there

Tags: postgresql

i have a postgres db here where i can get the data from like so:

```
SELECT * FROM berlinBuildingFootprints
```

it returns all data from that table. when i want to receive on single datapoint like this:

```
SELECT * FROM berlinBuildingFootprints WHERE id = 'DEBE00YYH600008C'
```

it does not return anything, even if i know that this is in the database!

[image]

waht is wrong here? is the query wrong?

thanks a lot for help!!

Comment: Can you provide some minimal example to reproduce this maybe https://onecompiler.com/postgresql. I can guess by looking at the image but that may or may not help. So it'll help if you provide a minimal example to your problem

Comment: Looks like a blank or invisible character or something similar.

Comment: Please try `SELECT * FROM berlinBuildingFootprints WHERE TRIM(id) = 'DEBE00YYH600008C';`

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong quotes. `'id' = 'DEBC...'` compares a literal text value of `'id'` to your target, so you're just comparing two different text constants. You probably wanted `"id"='DEBC...'` to compare the *column* named `id` to the target.

Double quotes are for identifiers, single quotes for constants/literals. [Doc warns about this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> A string constant in SQL is an arbitrary sequence of characters bounded by single quotes (`'`), for example `'This is a string'`. To include a single-quote character within a string constant, write two adjacent single quotes, e.g., `'Dianne''s horse'`. Note that this is not the same as a double-quote character (`"`).

If it still doesn't work with the right quotes, you can inspect the value a bit closer: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/SbzPDdhM)

```sql
select quote_literal(id),
       string_to_array(id,null) as characters,
       (select array_agg(ascii(x)) from string_to_table(id,null)_(x)) as codes,
       md5(id),
       sha256(id::bytea)
from (select id from berlinBuildingFootprints where ogc_fid=2260957 
      union all select 'DEBE00YYH600008C') a;
```

| quote_literal | characters | codes | md5 | sha256 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'DEBEO0YYН600OO8С ' | {D,E,B,E,O,0,Y,Y,Н,6,0,0,O,O,8,С," "," "} | {68,69,66,69,79,48,89,89,1053,54,48,48,79,79,56,1057,32,9} | b73a00d70a9cb9648562f439c405ba84 | \xb71e3118fab4f0e6c56e889ee3b1e6bbc2c3bf6559344af91043d343b40df5b5 |
| 'DEBE00YYH600008C' | {D,E,B,E,0,0,Y,Y,H,6,0,0,0,0,8,C} | {68,69,66,69,48,48,89,89,72,54,48,48,48,48,56,67} | 71d7878fa23f6d64cd9d18f09ead1b5e | \x35be25e5f87b7149d82c304e42a2707c08ce8363bcc14dbc952a792201980851 |

```sql
select a.n, 
       a.a, ascii(a.a), 
       b.b, ascii(b.b), 
       a.a is not distinct from b.b is_equal
from berlinBuildingFootprints x,
     string_to_table(id,null) with ordinality as a(a,n) full outer join 
     string_to_table('DEBE00YYH600008C',null) with ordinality as b(b,n) on a.n=b.n
where x.ogc_fid=2260957;
```

| n | a | ascii | b | ascii | is_equal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | D | 68 | D | 68 | t |
| 2 | E | 69 | E | 69 | t |
| 3 | B | 66 | B | 66 | t |
| 4 | E | 69 | E | 69 | t |
| 5 | O | **79** | 0 | **48** | **F** |
| 6 | 0 | 48 | 0 | 48 | t |
| 7 | Y | 89 | Y | 89 | t |
| 8 | Y | 89 | Y | 89 | t |
| 9 | Н | **1053** | H | **72** | **F** |
| 10 | 6 | 54 | 6 | 54 | t |
| 11 | 0 | 48 | 0 | 48 | t |
| 12 | 0 | 48 | 0 | 48 | t |
| 13 | O | **79** | 0 | **48** | **F** |
| 14 | O | **79** | 0 | **48** | **F** |
| 15 | 8 | 56 | 8 | 56 | t |
| 16 | С | **1057** | C | **67** | **F** |
| 17 |  | 32 | *null* | *null* | **F** |
| 18 |  | 9 | *null* | *null* | **F** |

Comment: Yes, that's a clear contrast between the example query and the previous queries in the screen-dump supplied. The previous queries use `id like '<constant>'` and presumably worked. The example query uses the plainly false `'id' = '<constant>'`.

Answer (score -1):

In the spirit of Mandy and Laurenz's points, you could also try ..

```
SELECT * FROM berlinBuildingFootprints WHERE 'DEBE00YYH600008C' in id
```

... or ...

```
SELECT * FROM berlinBuildingFootprints WHERE id LIKE 'DEBE00YYH600008C%'
```

Both queries allow for trailing whitespace. The former query also allows for leading whitespace. The latter query allows for any string that starts with the characters before the % sign.

Comment: There's no built-in `text in text` operator, so the first example would give you a syntax error. [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XAW4kCH6)