# Duplicate records are getting inserted in table violating the primary key constraint in postgresql 15.0

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-15

I'm using 15.0 version of PostgreSQL. I am facing a strange issue where duplicate data is getting inserted in table violating the primary key. Where as not all the query is showing the duplicate records. But after doing one `VACUUM (FULL)` on the table the duplicate row started showing in all the queries.

I'm seeing this 2nd time here. Previously `txndatetime` was a part of composite primary key. I thought  this may be due to the fact that Postgres might be storing the timestamp as epoch which is a real number in Postgres. We changed it as a long column `dt_epoch`. Still we are seeing this. BTW the table is a hash partitioned table .

The version:

```sql
select version();
```

| version |
| --- |
| PostgreSQL 15.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44), 64-bit |

The table structure:

```sql
\d my_table
```

> ```sql
> Partitioned table "my_table"
> ```

| Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| grp_id | character varying(100) |  | not null |  |
| txn_id | character varying(100) |  | not null |  |
| rec_dt | date |  | not null |  |
| creation_ts | timestamp without time zone |  | not null |  |
| created_by_user_id | character varying(50) |  | not null |  |
| crtd_by_client_id | character varying(50) |  | not null |  |
| txndatetime | timestamp with time zone |  | not null |  |
| rrn | character varying(150) |  |  |  |
| dt_epoch | bigint |  | not null |  |

> ```sql
> Partition key: HASH (grp_id)
>
> Indexes:
>    "my_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (grp_id, txn_id, dt_epoch)
>    "my_table_grp_id_idx" btree (grp_id)
>    "my_table_creation_ts_idx" btree (creation_ts)
>    "my_table_txn_id_idx" btree (txn_id)
> Number of partitions: 8 (Use \d+ to list them.)
> ```

The record that showing the duplicate results:

```sql
select grp_id, txn_id, txndatetime, dt_epoch, rec_dt 
from my_table 
where rec_dt = '2024-02-21';
```

| grp_id | txn_id | txndatetime | dt_epoch | rec_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ210220241522100001 | 2698e117-1cd1-4705-97cb-8a0fc65907d | 2024-02-21 15:21:13+05:30 | 1708509073000 | 2024-02-21 |
| XYZ210220241522100001 | 07da7715-e67e-4ff2-a000-9f2e999fbd8 | 2024-02-21 15:21:13+05:30 | **1708509073000** | 2024-02-21 |
| **XYZ210220241532100001** | **7b68ca16-c955-4526-9a40-124b1b215b2** | 2024-02-21 15:31:39+05:30 | **1708509699000** | 2024-02-21 |
| **XYZ210220241532100001** | **7b68ca16-c955-4526-9a40-124b1b215b2** | 2024-02-21 15:31:39+05:30 | **1708509699000** | 2024-02-21 |
| XYZ210220241532100001 | 9cc5e877-27ff-49ee-812c-1b0b48e8418 | 2024-02-21 15:31:39+05:30 | 1708509699000 | 2024-02-21 |
| XYZ210220241246100001 | 7f105788-89f3-4742-a642-43b551ab6e0 | 2024-02-21 12:45:33+05:30 | 1708499733000 | 2024-02-21 |

Whereas after limiting it with `rec_dt`, `grp_id` and `txn_id` it shows only one row:

```sql
select * from my_table 
where rec_dt = '2024-02-21' 
and grp_id='XYZ210220241532100001' 
and txn_id='7b68ca16-c955-4526-9a40-124b1b215b2';
```

| grp_id | txn_id | rec_dt | creation_ts | created_by_user_id | created_by_org_id | txndatetime | rrn | dt_epoch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ210220241532100001 | 7b68ca16-c955-4526-9a40-124b1b215b2 | 2024-02-21 | 2024-02-21 15:32:31.465 | 1056832970 | NPCI | 2024-02-21 15:31:39+05:30 | 405215100006 | 1708509699000 |

Again with `grp_id` search it is not showing the said row multiple times:

```sql
select grp_id, txn_id, txndatetime, dt_epoch, rec_dt 
from my_table 
where  grp_id='XYZ210220241532100001';
```

| grp_id | txn_id | txndatetime | dt_epoch | rec_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ210220241532100001 | 7b68ca16-c955-4526-9a40-124b1b215b2 | 2024-02-21 15:31:39+05:30 | 1708509699000 | 2024-02-21 |
| XYZ210220241532100001 | 9cc5e877-27ff-49ee-812c-1b0b48e8418 | 2024-02-21 15:31:39+05:30 | 1708509699000 | 2024-02-21 |

Now after doing a `VACUUM (FULL)` on that table all the query started showing the duplicate rows:

```sql
DGschema=# VACUUM (FULL) DGschema.my_table;
```

> ```
> VACUUM
> ```

```sql
select grp_id, txn_id, txndatetime, dt_epoch, rec_dt 
from my_table 
where rec_dt = '2024-02-21';
```

| grp_id | txn_id | txndatetime | dt_epoch | rec_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ210220241522100001 | 2698e117-1cd1-4705-97cb-8a0fc65907d | 2024-02-21 15:21:13+05:30 | 1708509073000 | 2024-02-21 |
| XYZ210220241522100001 | 07da7715-e67e-4ff2-a000-9f2e999fbd8 | 2024-02-21 15:21:13+05:30 | 1708509073000 | 2024-02-21 |
| **XYZ210220241532100001** | **7b68ca16-c955-4526-9a40-124b1b215b2** | 2024-02-21 15:31:39+05:30 | **1708509699000** | 2024-02-21 |
| **XYZ210220241532100001** | **7b68ca16-c955-4526-9a40-124b1b215b2** | 2024-02-21 15:31:39+05:30 | **1708509699000** | 2024-02-21 |
| XYZ210220241532100001 | 9cc5e877-27ff-49ee-812c-1b0b48e8418 | 2024-02-21 15:31:39+05:30 | 1708509699000 | 2024-02-21 |
| ABC210220241246100001 | 7f105788-89f3-4742-a642-43b551ab6e0 | 2024-02-21 12:45:33+05:30 | 1708499733000 | 2024-02-21 |

```sql
select grp_id, txn_id, txndatetime, dt_epoch, rec_dt, creation_ts 
from my_table 
where  grp_id='XYZ210220241532100001';
```

| grp_id | txn_id | txndatetime | dt_epoch | rec_dt | creation_ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **XYZ210220241532100001** | **7b68ca16-c955-4526-9a40-124b1b215b2** | 2024-02-21 15:31:39+05:30 | **1708509699000** | 2024-02-21 | 2024-02-21 15:32:31.465 |
| **XYZ210220241532100001** | **7b68ca16-c955-4526-9a40-124b1b215b2** | 2024-02-21 15:31:39+05:30 | **1708509699000** | 2024-02-21 | 2024-02-21 15:32:36.511 |
| XYZ210220241532100001 | 9cc5e877-27ff-49ee-812c-1b0b48e8418 | 2024-02-21 15:31:39+05:30 | 1708509699000 | 2024-02-21 | 2024-02-21 15:32:50.487 |

This is dangerous bug in Postgres which is defying the basics and making PostgreSQL unreliable. Is it a bug in this PostgreSQL version?

Comment: Keep in mind `grp_id`, `txn_id` are character types, so you might be overlooking the difference. To inspect those, you should run them through some functions (`quote_literal()`, `ascii()`) that will make each part of their value visible. [Here's an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77343845/5298879)

Comment: What do you get if you run `select tableoid::regclass, * from my_table where  grp_id='XYZ210220241532100001';`? System column [`tableoid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) should give you the partition table the duplicates come from: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/S60KT2Aj).

Comment: it is the same partition where both the rows were there. this is declarative partition and has the same index. Got other duplicate case in different partition also